# How to open new view with condition IF

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show new `ViewController`, just when Text Fields are not empty or are not same. Always when I click button which navigate user to next view, do it, even when conditions are not met.

```
@IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLastRegisterView", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if usernameTextField.text == "" || passwordTextField.text == "" || confirmedPasswordTextField.text == "" {
        errorLabel.isHidden = false
        errorLabel.text = "All fields are required"
    }
    else{
        if passwordTextField.text == confirmedPasswordTextField.text{
            if segue.identifier == "goToLastRegisterView"{
                let secondRegisterVC = segue.destination as! RegisterSecondViewController
                secondRegisterVC.userName = usernameTextField.text!
                secondRegisterVC.password = passwordTextField.text!

            }
        }
        else{
            errorLabel.isHidden = false
            errorLabel.text = "Different passwords"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did `self.performSegue(withIdentifier:` it's to late to check textfeilds inside `override func prepare(for` you have to do it in button action

```
@IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if usernameTextField.text == "" || passwordTextField.text == "" || confirmedPasswordTextField.text == "" {
        errorLabel.isHidden = false
        errorLabel.text = "All fields are required"
        return 
    }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLastRegisterView", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution didn't help me. I changed code with advice, but new ViewController is still open even when Text Fields are empty or Passwords Text Fields are different.

Comment: you should drag the segue source from the vc itself in IB not from the button

Comment: This is it! I dragged the segue sorce from Button not ViewController! Thank you so much

Comment: You can also keep the segue from the button and implement `shouldPerform(segueWithIdentifier:)`